# How can I add left and right borders for one of the UITabBar items?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

If you look at the image below, you'll see two vertical lines -- isolating the middle tab item. (The lines are faint)

In code, how can I create these two lines?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:
1. add selected Image with lines in .png
2. set background image with lines and change this image depend on selected tab.
3. create your own view, inherited from `UIView` and add it as subview (in this case you have to implement own switch logic)

Answer (score 0):

```
 This will help you to add the seperators
//Add seperators Line
        if let items = self.tabBar.items {
            //Get the height of the tab bar
            let height = self.tabBar.bounds.height
            let width = self.tabBar.bounds.width

//Calculate the size of the items
            let numItems = CGFloat(items.count)
            let itemSize = CGSize(
                width: tabBar.frame.width / numItems,
                height: tabBar.frame.height)

            for (index, _) in items.enumerated() {
                //We don't want a separator on the left of the first item.
                if index > 0 {

//Xposition of the item
                    let xPosition = itemSize.width * CGFloat(index)

                    let separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(
                        x: xPosition, y: 0, width: 3.5, height: height))
                    separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                    tabBar.insertSubview(separator, at: 1)
               }
           }
```

extension UIImage {

```
class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    color.setFill()
    UIRectFill(rect)
    let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

}